# Package missing from texlive?

Tags: apt, package-management, 19.10, latex, texlive

I have the latest texlive distribution, which I installed via `sudo apt install texlive-full`

Now I would like to install the package **tuda-ci**, which is available on CTAN [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tuda-ci). I am a bit confused: it sounds like the package is already part of texlive (it also says it [here](https://www.ce.tu-darmstadt.de/ce/latex_tuda/index.en.jsp)), however it is not on my system and I cannot find it as an Ubuntu package.

Can someone please explain this to me? What is the preferred way to install in this case?

Comment: You have to wait a week and upgrade to 20.04 LTS - it [has TUDA](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=tuda).

Answer (score 0):

I usually install texlive from .iso Images downloaded from here: [Acquiring TeX Live as an ISO image](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html). It seems to contain any texlive packages.

But you should probably remove any installed TeX packages:

```
sudo apt remove --purge texlive*
```